# Does a kernel driver implementing mmap() have to create a character device?

Tags: linux-kernel, buffer, driver, mmap, dma

I am trying to write a kernel driver to manage some memory blocks of physically contiguous and DMAable memory (I am using `kmalloc()` since these are only DMA streams).  To pull some functionality into userspace, this memory is to be `mmap()`ed with its own implementation of `mmap()`.  I have been using *Linux Device Drivers* and the bad examples that show up in Google as my main source of information.

My `mmap()` (calling it `my_mmap()` for now) needs to be registered with the kernel.  It appears the only valid way to do this using a `struct file_operations`, but this requires creating a character device and a physical location for it.  I do not want to do that.  I just want to create a virtual address for the userspace application to access the memory buffers and not create any files to map the memory buffers to.  Is this possible?

I did find that frame buffers also have an equivalent structure with an `mmap()` implementation, but that would be too much of a hack.  That and it adds more unknowns.

As I understand it, `my_mmap()` can do the heavy lifting and use `remap_pfn_range()` as long as I am ok with the lost flexibility.  Otherwise I would have to implement a local `nopages()` and register it using a `struct vm_operations_struct`.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mmap()` operation is a request from userspace to map some source into its virtual address space.  The way that the userspace program identifies *which* source it is interested in is by supplying a file descriptor (which is really just a handle on a resource known to the kernel).

This means that you have to make your device representable as a file descriptor so that a userspace program can tell the kernel that it's interested in it (and the kernel knows to call your `mmap()` implementation) - registering a character device is the typical way to do that.  Note that frame buffer devices are accessed through character devices, too.

You do not have to implement other character device operations like `read()` and `write()` if it does not make sense for your device.  A character device is simply a way for a userspace program to open a kernel-managed handle to the device.

Comment: I am already using Netlink for some communications.  So I could take the `struct socket * sock` that is passed to netlink_create, access the `ops` field (a `struct struct_proto_ops`) and modify the `mmap` field in `ops`.  Would that work?

Comment: Correction, Netlink uses a `netlink_ops` variable for all sock->ops to point to.  So I have to copy `netlink_ops` and modify the `mmap` field.

Comment: @Joshua, what you suggest may work, but I just don't see the point of hacking the kernel instead of doing things the normal way. With the normal way, you have a better chance to avoid bad surprises.

Comment: @Joshua: It will probably work to add an `mmap()` handler to your netlink socket, but it would be a little bit odd.

Comment: @Joshua, I cannot say if mmap() can be used without any file, but creating exactly a character device is not necessary. In my project, I create a file in debugfs, which is easier, and use that to be able to mmap a buffer in the kernel space to the user space and pass data through it. [Here is the code](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/utils/simple_trace_recorder/kernel/module.c), see `buffer_mmap_fault()` and `buffer_file_mmap()` there. Perhaps it could be helpful.